# ML Kit Firebase translate text null Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin, translate, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit

I'm a newbie in android so sorry in advance, I'm inside a fun that use the user's input and translate it before sending the data to firebase Database, I think I'm doing something wrong with the variables because in the loop I can get the language text "en" but just after its null so the translation can't start..

```
     println("SAVING DATABASE")

    var theLangue:String? = null
    var detect:String? = null

    val languageIdentifier = LanguageIdentification.getClient()
    languageIdentifier.identifyPossibleLanguages(userText)
        .addOnSuccessListener { identifiedLanguages ->

            for (identifedLanguage in identifiedLanguages) {

                detect = identifedLanguage.languageTag
                val confidence = identifedLanguage.confidence
                println(" LANGUAGE DETECTED: $detect , LANGUAGE CONFIDENCE: $confidence")

            }
            theLangue = detect

        }.addOnFailureListener {

        println("problem cant translate!")
    }



    println("Translate pre build ${theLangue.toString()} ++ $theLangue")   //todo NULL
    val options = TranslatorOptions.Builder()
        .setSourceLanguage(theLangue.toString()) // todo NULL
        .setTargetLanguage(Locale.getDefault().displayLanguage)
        .build()

    val theTranslator = Translation.getClient(options)
    val conditions = DownloadConditions.Builder()
        .requireWifi()
        .build()
    theTranslator.downloadModelIfNeeded(conditions)
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            println("succes downloading models languages.. going to translate wait..")
            theTranslator.translate(userText)
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    // Translation successful.
                    println("Succes translated text")
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                    // Error.
                    // ...
                    println("there is a problem failed to transalte !")
                }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            // Model couldn’t be downloaded or other internal error.
            // ...
            println(exception.message)
            println(exception.localizedMessage)
            println("cant download languages models !")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.addOnSuccessListener` is an async call, which may not be executed right away.

A quick fix is to move the translate logic into the `addOnSuccessListener` callback in language identification.

`
...
languageIdentifier.identifyPossibleLanguages(userText)
.addOnSuccessListener { identifiedLanguages ->

```
        for (identifedLanguage in identifiedLanguages) {

            detect = identifedLanguage.languageTag
            val confidence = identifedLanguage.confidence
            println(" LANGUAGE DETECTED: $detect , LANGUAGE CONFIDENCE: $confidence")

        }
        theLangue = detect


      val options = TranslatorOptions.Builder()
        .setSourceLanguage(theLangue.toString()) // todo NULL
        .setTargetLanguage(Locale.getDefault().displayLanguage)
        .build()
      
      val theTranslator = Translation.getClient(options)
      ...

    }.addOnFailureListener {

    println("problem cant translate!")
}
...
```

`

To improve the code readability, you could use the [continueWithTask](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task#continueWithTask(com.google.android.gms.tasks.Continuation%3CTResult,%20com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task%3CTContinuationResult%3E%3E)).